# put "</script>" in a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to put "`</script>`" in a variable in JavaScript but it will be consider as end tag like below example:

```
<script>     
content.value = aval + '<script> ma_gallery("' + varimgurl + '");</script>'+ sevom;
</script>
```

Does anyone know a solution ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `'<\/script>'`.

In a string literal, an escaped slash is equivalent to a slash so it makes no difference to the JavaScript parser but it breaks up the end tag syntax so it isn't parsed as an end tag by the HTML parser.

(An alternative is to split it up into two strings and concatenate them together, but that is more typing, harder to read, and (albeit not significantly) less efficient).

Comment: Escaping any of the characters except the left angle bracket `<` will work

Comment: @blgt — If you escape the t you'll have a tab instead of the letter t. Escaping the `/` is traditional, so it is the sensible choice.

Comment: @Quentin Good poin\t, forgot the `t`

Comment: now this will not be considered end tag @Quentin ? need little elaboration please

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Unlike Javascript, the HTML parser ignores escape sequences with backslashes. "\/" is a backslash followed by a slash, not a single slash.

Answer (score 2):

Split `"</script>"` into two strings:

```
content.value = aval + '<script> ma_gallery("' + varimgurl + '");</scr' + 'ipt>' + sevom;
```